Azure Index Search odd behavior
There are some odd results in the index that I'm currently using.
I'm using the simple query and searching on multiple fields, I added a scoring profile to boost the Title property of the data (currently the title has a weight of 50 and address 1) but for some reason, I still have odd results when searching here is more information:
Search value (I add '*' at the end of the search once I make the request):
Northern Trust M

Example of result:
  {
    "@search.score": 4.0503893,
    "Title": "Northern Trust Minneapolis",
    "Address": "80 South Eighth Street Minneapolis 55402"
  },
  {
    "@search.score": 3.9770052,
    "Title": "Northern Trust Indianapolis",
    "Address": "55 Monument Circle Indianapolis 46204"
  },
  {
    "@search.score": 3.9543731,
    "Title": "Northern Trust Miami",
    "Address": "600 Brickell Ave Miami 33131"
  },
  {
    "@search.score": 3.946587,
    "Title": "Northern Trust Montecito",
    "Address": "1485 East Valley Road Montecito 93108"
  }

In the example the "Northern Trust Indianapolis" has a higher score than "Northern Trust Miami". Does anyone knows why? Or could give any tips how to make a better query in this case?
I tried modifying the query with '+' and '*' operators but I could not achieve a good result, I would like to have title matches with better score

I believe that Northern Trust Indianapolis has the address starting with M that is why, but since the title weight is so much higher I'm not sure why it is impacting the search

use JSON query  {   "search": "Northern Trust M*",   "scoringProfile": "boostTitle",   "queryType": "simple" }

with  "scoringProfiles": [     {       "name": "boostTitle",       "text": {         "weights": {           "Title": 50,           "Address": 1         }       }     }   ]

To address the odd scoring results in your Azure Cognitive Search where exact matches in the fields are boosted, you can use a combination of scoring profiles and analyze patterns in your search queries. The example below demonstrates how to set up your index, documents, and scoring profile to achieve better search results.

Define the index schema with the necessary fields and a scoring profile that boosts the title field. Here's a sample index:

Index:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://sampath.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC7ED3C571FF28\"",
  "name": "azuresql-index80",
  "defaultScoringProfile": "sampath",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Title",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Address",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "sampath",
      "functionAggregation": "sum",
      "text": {
        "weights": {
          "Title": 50,
          "Address": 1
        }
      },
      "functions": []
    }
  ],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": null,
  "vectorSearch": null
}



To add a scoring profile in the Azure portal, include the field name and weight.


The JSON query editor below is used to search for items in the Azure Cognitive Search index, utilizing a scoring profile that boosts a specific field.

{
  "search": "Northern Trust M*",
  "scoringProfile": "sampath",
  "queryType": "simple"
}

Output:



That is exactly what I did with my scoring profile, I noticed a huge difference in the score of the items in your search compared to my search, do you know what could be the problem? I'm passing all the parameters

Please try with my scoring profile and query. Rerun the indexer after adding scoring profile to the index.
